# Inserting image to Markdown file doesn't work locally and remotely

Tags: image, github, markdown

I have read info about inserting images to Github `readme.md` file.

It is described here: [Markdown mastering](https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/).

I tried following in my markdown file:

`![Front-end & Back-end Architecture](/frontend-backend view.png)`

Locally it looks:

[image]

And remotely it looks the same. Like some text instead of the image:

[image]

The image is exactly at the root folder and has to be accessible without any problems.

**UPDATE:**

I have changed to the following:

`![Front-end & Back-end Architecture](frontend-backend-view.png)`

And now it works on **Github**.
However, it fails on **BitBucket**:

[image]

It shows broken images.

***What's wrong with this syntax?***

Comment: add `./frontend-backend-view.png`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid spaces in whites and if it is in the same directory remove the spaces bar :

❌<strike>![Front-end & Back-end Architecture](/frontend-backend view.png)</strike>

✅ `![Front-end & Back-end Architecture](frontend-backend-view.png)`

---

### Jetbrains Bug

This is due to the bug of the JetBrains plugin that obtains faults when rendering the image.

A possible solution is to **restart the IDE** or **reopen the file.**

### Similiar cases

In visual code this occurs when images are detected as harmful. Your solution is in the `allow dangerous content`.

#### Example and solution

- We get the message and we do not see the image ...

[image: 01]

- We accept the warning ... by clicking on the little window ...

[image: Solution]

- Now we will see our image :

[image]
*If you can not solve it, comment on it and investigate in a more adequate and thorough answer*.

Comment: I have fixed to following: `![Front-end & Back-end Architecture](frontend-backend-view.png)`. Now it works for Github. However, it fails for BitBucket.

Comment: @nazar_art https://bitbucket.org/<user-name>/<repo-name>/raw/<branch-     name>/<path>   <br> `[Your Link Text](https://bitbucket.org/username/reponame/raw/master/path/to/image.jpg)`

Comment: I tried following `![Additional Plugins](https://bitbucket.org/nazar_art/pdf2data/raw/TR-2714/load/info/additional-plugins.png)` it also fails

Comment: @nazar_art I trying with more solutions